# 2 Subnets see each other

Tags: networking, vpn, dd-wrt, subnet

I have 2 routers that need to be on different subnets.  The reason is that router 1 is connected to the internet outside the US where I live.  Router 2 is behind router 1 and has a VPN server continually running so that I can access US sites.  One is 192.168.1.1 the other is  192.168.9.1.  I run dd-wrt on router 2 (the VPN server).  The other is stock linksys.  I would like computers connected to either network to see each other.  Is this possible?  I have searched high and low and usually the responses are why do you need 2 subnets? Well I do for this to work.

I tried a network bridge on my main computer via wifi and ethernet, this kinda worked until obviously the computer was off.  Any ideas? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You will need to add some routes in the routing table. [This link](http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work) might help you understand them.

Answer (score 1):

If you run windows, you can add a secondary network to any NIC, the same applies to linux, though in both cases you will probably need to set up routes if you want the machines to be able to use both gateways. If they are then connected to an unmanaged switch, any machine should be able to see both networks without issue.